# Evaluating properties of GPO-created firewall rules in a script

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-firewall

On a Server 2008 R2 machine, I would like to use Powershell to query the list of "remote addresses" for a specific rule. The rule in question has been created through a group policy applying to the machine.

I know there is `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=<name>` as well as the list returned by `(New-object –comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2).rules`, but both seem to only include rules which have been defined locally and do not list any of the rules created by the firewall GPO extension.

How do I conveniently get at the properties of policy-created rules?

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to parsing the strings which are written to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\FirewallRules` by the group policy firewall extension. This is what the raw registry value data might look like for a specific rule:

```
v2.10|Action=Allow|Active=TRUE|Dir=In|Protocol=6|LPort=5666|RA4=192.168.21.55|RA4=192.168240.10|RA4=192.168.240.11|RA4=192.168.240.12|App=%ProgramFiles%\NSClient++\nscp.exe|Name=NSClient++ Monitoring Agent|Desc=Allow NSClient/NRPE connections from Nagios servers|
```

As those are `Name=Value` pairs of data where *"Name"* is not unique, there is some more work than just a series of `Split()` calls, but it still sufficiently clean to work with in PowerShell v2 and onwards:

```
Function Get-GPOFirewallRules()
{
    $regPath="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\FirewallRules"

    # fetch rule value strings from registry into an array of strings, 
    # map version info and GPO rule ID into fields in string
    $rulesRaw = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $regPath).PSObject.Properties | `
                Where-Object { $_.Name -like "{[0-9A-F\-]*}" } | `
                Select-Object "Name", "Value" | `
                ForEach-Object { $_.Value -replace "^(v[0-9\.]*)\|", `
                                                   "GPOID=$($_.Name)|GPOVERSION=`$1|" }

    # construct a result set of hashtables 
    $rulesRaw | ForEach-Object {
        $rule=@{}            # initialize as hashtable
        $_.Split("|") | ForEach-Object {
            $name = $_.Split("=")[0]
            $value = $_.Split("=")[1]
            # for multi-valued names, cast to array and add value element
            If ($rule.ContainsKey($name)) {
                $rule.$name = [array]($rule.$name) + $value
            } Else {
                $rule.Add($name, $value)
            }
        } # $_.Split("|") | ForEach-Object
        $rule
    } #$rulesRaw | ForEach-Object
}
```

The output is a list of hashtables where key names have been derived from the respective registry field names and the values are either strings or arrays of strings:

```
Get-GPOFirewallRules

Action                         Allow
GPOVERSION                     v2.10
Dir                            In
Desc                           Allow NSClient/NRPE connections from Nagios servers
Name                           NSClient++ Monitoring Agent
Active                         TRUE
RA4                            {192.168.21.55, 192.168.240.10, 192.168.240.11, 192.168.240.12}
App                            %ProgramFiles%\NSClient++\nscp.exe
Protocol                       6
LPort                          5666
GPOID                          {1FEFA84F-0779-4279-9C02-F5678C949304}

Action                         Allow
GPOVERSION                     v2.10
Dir                            In
Name                           Allow ICMP for Monitoring und Management     
Active                         TRUE
RA4                            {192.168.21.55, 192.168.3.60, 192.168.3.61, 192.168.8.0/255.255.255.0...}
ICMP4                          {3:*, 8:*, 11:*}
Protocol                       1
GPOID                          {6CA2C52C-6AD6-4513-B197-3702637BD9DF}
```

The naming scheme is different from what `(New-object –comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2).rules` is returning and the structure seems to be slightly different (and likely subject to change in future Windows versions) too, but it seems to serve its purpose for now.